# Use regular Admob + custom publisher in same view

Tags: android, admob

I'm using **Admob SDK** and **Tobonet SDK**.

Using each of them in separate view control works fine.

Now I'm using mediation - after implemented code for custom event - works fine, but still using separate views. Now my goal is to use one view control. But **Admob** and **Tobonet** have different declaration for view which countains advertisement.

Is it good idea to have two views on same position on screen and make invisible/visible switch depending on current ad?

If somebody managed to use one view control - please help me!

**Update** Managed to solve how to use booth providers on same possition. Still don't know are the Admob use same view /for custom server banner/ or switches ad views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this guide](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/ads/mobile-ads-sdk/mediation/custom-events/banners) for full instructions on implementing custom events.

When you implement a custom event, you request an ad from a 3rd party ad network (in this case Tobonet), and when the ad network returns an ad, you invoke:

```
MediationBannerListener.onReceivedAd(View);
```

The AdMob SDK just displays that view within a container `AdView`. So the view hierarchy looks like this:

```
YourMainLayout
--com.google.ads.AdView (mediation container view with no ad)
----Tobonet ad View (contains the ad)
```

When getting AdMob ads through the mediation network, your view hierarchy actually looks like this:

```
YourMainLayout
--com.google.ads.AdView (mediation container view with no ad)
----com.google.ads.AdView (contains the ad)
```

The AdMob Mediation handles the view switching for you - on a refresh, it rips out any views inside of the mediation container, and replaces it with the new view from the next ad network. You don't need to handle the view's visibility yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Actually my problem is because Tobonet starts its own timer refresh logic instead of waiting Admob to do this. So instead of have switching 50/50 ads as managed from site - long series admob then long series tobonet ads. I wrote to tobonet developers for this issue. Hope they will solve it